# Exempt authentication if request if from frontend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, ruby-on-rails-4

I got a newbie or maybe even a stupid question.

So i'm trying to learn Rails 4 with frontend Angular2. So I know it's not advisable but for demo purposes i'd like to send a request from Angular to my Rails without any authentication needed. Is that possible? How?

Thanks

Comment: How are you authenticating the requests?

Comment: No there's no authentication. That's my question actually can I do it without authentication?

Comment: Yes, you can. No one's asking you to authenticate the requests. There's no need to authenticate if you don't need to. Just send normal requests to the api end points

Comment: Sorry, just last question, is it possible to use token authentication on non-api rails application with angular?

Comment: Yes, you can. I'd suggest jwt for that. There are some good tutorials on that.

Comment: Okay thank you very much!